# Como realizar configuração de arquivos para muitos Targets?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple

Como posso configurar o Xcode para realizar a seguinte tarefa:
 Utilizar 1 Target como template de outros targets, e que algum arquivo/classe ao ser incluído ou alterado, neste template, possa ser referenciados nos outros targets já criados.

E cada arquivo/classe que seja inserido no Target "filho" não seja referenciado pelos outros targets, somente naquele onde foi criado.

Comment: Acho que o que você quer fazer na verdade é, criar um target do tipo "framework", da uma olhada [nesse link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios) talvez possa ajudar.

Comment: Não sei se chega a ser um framework. Mas seria um modo de refletir a inclusão de uma nova classe em um target template, e automaticamente ocorrer um include nos outros targets já criados.Embora o Xcode ofereça essa opção quando criamos uma classe, gostaria que isso fosse automatico, e não manual.

Comment: Então o que você quer na verdade é, ter mais de um target no mesmo projeto, esses targets compartilham o mesmo código, cada target é compilado de acordo com a configuração de Xcode que ele utilizar, é isso? Se for, sim é possível e sim eu tenho a resposta, pois já utilizei algo assim em um projeto que desenvolvi.

Comment: Sim, o importante é que eu possa compartilhar novos arquivos para todos os targets de maneira automatica, pois serao muitas versoes. E com isso reduzir o tempo de producao e minimizar falhas do tipo "ah esqueci de copiar aqela classe!"

Comment: Eu tive um dia mega corrido (e ainda estou na correria), vou escrever a resposta agora.

Answer (score 1):

Pra responder sua pergunta, vou usar uma situação que aconteceu comigo e deu muito certo no final, apesar de parecer um pouco trabalhoso, depois fica muito simples.

Vamos imaginar a seguinte situação: Seu app interage com 4 ambientes, **local**, **development**, **staging** e **production** e você quer que o Xcode exporte 1 app para cada ambiente mas você quer ter as 4 versões no seu device, é possível fazer isso?

Bom para começar, acho que vale a pena baixar um projeto que já usa esse tipo de recurso no Xcode, eu sugiro usar o [Facebook POP](https://github.com/facebook/pop) por que foi a partir dele que aprendi a usar as configurações para targets específicos no projeto.

O commit que usei para dar de exemplo é : `038f29b2de47db3fce803c5a180eee604ebe1977`.

Depois que baixar o projeto, abra o workspace e selecione o arquivo do projeto, selecione a aba *"Info"* e veja o item *"Configurations"*.

[image: Configurations]

Esse item lista a quantidade de **tipos de configuração** que o Xcode vai utilizar para compilar o seu projeto, você pode duplicar quantas você precisar a partir das duas configurações padrões que são *Debug* e *Release*.

Neste exemplo eu fiz o seguinte:

- **Local & Development** réplica de **Debug**
- **Staging & Production** réplica de **Release**

Pra cada configuração, você pode também adicionar o arquivo de extensão `xcconfig`, esse arquivo é uma espécie de modificador da configuração listada. Neste exemplo, vai haver a necessidade de editar alguns parâmetros via `xcconfig` que são compartilhados entres os targets, e em outros casos, cada target vai ter sua particularidade, exemplo, `PRODUCT_NAME` é o atributo que define o nome que aparece na home screen do iOS, para que cada versão do app apareça com um nome diferente na home screen, preciso apontar um `xcconfig` para a respectiva configuração.

Também é possível dar `include` de um `xcconfig` no outro e é isso que possibilita compartilhar parametros entre eles, se você ver no Pop, o arquivo `Base-iOS.xcconfig` por exemplo é exatamente isso.

Bom continuando, supondo que criamos um `xcconfig` para cada target, agora posso definir um nome individual para cada um assim:

```
PRODUCT_NAME=App Local // Dentro do `xcconfig` de local
PRODUCT_NAME=App Dev // Dentro do `xcconfig` de development
PRODUCT_NAME=App Stg // Dentro do `xcconfig` de staging
PRODUCT_NAME=Appname // Dentro do `xcconfig` de production
```

Isso é só um exemplo, você pode fazer muito mais, como por exemplo, criar uma macro de pre processamento que compila seu app com perfil para *local*, *dev*, *stg*, *prod*. O código vai continuar compartilhado porem o compilador vai ignorar as partes que não interessam para você em determinados ambientes.

No Pop é bem claro isso, por que ele usa exatamente o mesmo código fonte para 3 targets diferentes e ele compartilha não só o static lib mas também o código não compilado.

Mais uma coisa, neste exemplo que eu dei, as maiores inconveniências foram que primeiro, tive que criar um AppId no developer portal para cada configuração, segundo, tive que criar um provisioning profile para cada uma das configurações também, no caso de testar *In-App Purchases* também tive que criar um *"beta"* do app no iTunes Connect.

No fim eu tinha 4 apps que eram o mesmo código fonte, com algumas diferenças relativas ao perfil do ambiente, rodando no mesmo device.

Talvez você não precise de tanto, mas a arquitetura utilizada com os `xcconfig` + os perfis de configuração, podem ser suficientes pra vc.

#### Bonus

Caso você use entitlements no seu projeto, você vai precisar rodar um script para que ele seja copiado no seu target, por que se você fazer esse setup no seu Xcode, para ele continua sendo um executável (.app) e não vários.

O script abaixo você pode adicionar como um novo *Run script* no projeto:

```
# Copy entitlements file
echo "Copy entitlements file for configuration ${CONFIGURATION} to path: ${SRCROOT}/[NOME DO ARCHIVE GERADO PELO XCODE]/$PRODUCT_NAME.entitlements ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app"
cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/[NOME DO ARCHIVE GERADO PELO XCODE]/$PRODUCT_NAME.entitlements" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/$PRODUCT_NAME.app"
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Vou experimentar e logo ja digo como ficou!!

Comment: No meu caso, os targets, serão realmente apps diferentes.... vou ter que replicar muitas vezes o mesmo produto. :D Isso que procuro é uma possivel solução para suporte e correções que possam ser aplicados a todos os apps se necessário. :D Então estou procurando um meio de minimizar meu tempo de trabalho para coisas comuns para todos os apps.

Comment: Gostaria de conversar com vc a qualquer hora, para mim ficaria um bom horario a noite, e poderemos trocar uma idéia, que acha?

Comment: Claro, semana que vem to mais tranquilo, você encontra meus contatos no meu perfil do Stack Overflow. Bom fim de semana, abraços!